# Multi-line raw string literals as preprocessor macros arguments

Tags: c++, c++11

Can a multi-line raw string literal be an argument of a preprocessor macro?

```
#define IDENTITY(x) x

int main()
{
    IDENTITY(R"(
    )");
}
```

This code doesn't compile in both g++4.7.2 and VC++11 (Nov.CTP).
Is it a compiler (lexer) bug?

Comment: It seems to be either a lexer or a pre-processor problem, in GCC at least. If I add a pre-processor line-continuation (ending the line in a backslash) it compiles, but the string contain the line-continuation character. Tested with GCC 4.7.2.

Comment: I've opened a bug to track the issue in the Visual C++ CTP.

Comment: For what it's worth, Clang 3.1 has no problem compiling your example.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple line macro invocations are legal - 
since you are using a raw string literal it should have compiled

There is a known GCC bug for this:

http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52852

If you had been using regular (nonraw) strings it would have been illegal.

This should have compiled:

```
printf(R"HELLO
    WORLD\n");
```

But not this:

```
printf("HELLO
    WORLD\n");
```

This should be coded as

```
printf("HELLO\nWORLD\n");
```

if a new line is intended between HELLO and WORLD or as

```
printf("HELLO "
    "WORLD\n");
```

If no intervening new line was intended.

Do you want a new line in your literal?  If so then couldn't you use

```
  IDENTITY("(\n)");
```

The C compiler documentation at

```
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp.pdf
```

States that in section 3.3 (Macro Arguments) that

```
"The invocation of the macro need not be 
restricted to a single logical line—it can cross 
as many lines in the source file as you wish."
```

Comment: Your first example doesn't compile because it's an ordinary string literal. The OP used a raw string literal, which can contain source-file newlines (see [lex.string], esp. para 4 & 5). I side with the OP that it's a compiler bug.

Comment: How can you do this in just C, not C++? `error: use of undeclared identifier 'R'`